# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource. Reason: Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to do some relations to my existing entities. After adding couple of ManyToOne relations between my tables. After dropping my prev tables Spring is suggesting that id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"). Not quite sure what's the problem

my entities:

```
public class Madeen implements Serializable {

  // TODO update to oracle sequence
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @CreatedDate
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
  private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private Organization organization;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "person_id")
  private String personId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name="status")
  private String status;
```

```
public class Debts {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private String personId;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "id")
    private Madeen MadeenId;

    @CreatedDate
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created_date", updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Instant updatedDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name= "debt_amount")
    private double debtAmount;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Organization organization;



}
```

Error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.tcc.madeen.entity.Madeen column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
at com.tcc.madeen.MadeenApplication.main(MadeenApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.tcc.madeen.entity.Madeen column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.tcc.madeen.entity.Madeen column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:895) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:913) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:637) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:359) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
... 20 common frames omitted

Comment: Your joinColumns are wrong. You should put organization_id, maden_id, etc... Check this out: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` above `organization`.

The name property of joincolumn refers to the database column in Madeen table where the organization_id is stored. Because Madeen already has a column id for it's own primary key you get this error.

Change `@JoinColumn(name = "id")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "organization_id")` in Madeen

And do the same for organization and madeen in Debts

For more info check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column) article.

Comment: This makes sense, although i keep receiving the same error

Comment: Actually it does work. I only had to change the relations of all tables to follow the same naming pattern. Thanks